# How to draw attached figure

Tags: tikz-arrows, flow-charts

This is what I have so far.. How can I make this figure attractive.

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Flowchart}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm and 6mm,
   arr/.style = {-Straight Barb, semithick},
     M/.style = {draw, outer sep = 1mm},
     N/.style = {M, rounded corners=3mm},
                    ]
\node (n1) [N] {text};
\node (n2) [M, right=of n1] {text};
\node (n3) [N, above right=of n2] {text};
\node (n4) [N, below right=of n2] {text};
%
\draw[arr] (n1) -- (n2);
\draw[arr] (n2) -- (n3);
\draw[arr] (n2) -- (n4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at TikZ manual, or [tikz.dev](https://tikz.dev/) if you prefer online documentation. Several things I can think of: 1. Use a different arrow style (for example `-latex`) 2. Set `fill` with some fancy colors. It is like art design, you can have your own preference :-)

Comment: What do you think is unattractive or boring with it? What is its context, i.e. what other information do you provide with the slide? Does the diagram support said message in any way?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with "make this figure attractive".

Comment: See also [shorten >=...] and [shorten <=...] (page 210).

Answer (score 1):

I would add the following details to make it more beautiful with more details about the flowchart:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My Flowchart}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 2mm and 6mm,
    arr/.style = {-Straight Barb, semithick, color=blue},
    M/.style = {draw, outer sep = 1mm, fill=red!30},
    N/.style = {M, rounded corners=3mm, fill=green!30},
]
\node (n1) [N, label=below:{Node 1}] {text};
\node (n2) [M, right=of n1, label=below:{Node 2}] {text};
\node (n3) [N, above right=of n2, label=right:{Node 3}] {text};
\node (n4) [N, below right=of n2, label=right:{Node 4}] {text};

\draw[arr] (n1) -- (n2);
\draw[arr] (n2) -- (n3);
\draw[arr] (n2) -- (n4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]